# Как подключиться к firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

При разработке приложения на Реакте появилась такая проблема. Есть Удаленная база данных Firebase, из которой мне нужно выгружать данные. Есть аналогичное приложение на Андроид, которое работает правильно без ошибок, а react-приложение не может подключиться к firebase. 
Скажу сразу, что у меня права доступа к базе настроены так:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Когда я выставляю значения свойств true я получаю доступ к базе, но не хочу так делать, так как я открываю свободный доступ к своей базе.
А вот код подключения к firebase из js приложения, здесь я вставляю конфиг, который мне сам firebase отдал:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const database = firebase.database();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

При `firebase.auth()` выдает `null`
При попытке вывести данные из базы я получаю такое сообщение:

> permission_denied at /restaurants: Client doesn't have permission to
>   access the desired data

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Права доступа настроены вполне нормально. То есть, такая запись вполне легальна:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Это можно найти здесь: [Get Started with Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart), ну и посмотреть для ознакомления тут тоже: [User Based Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Если на этой строке вы получаете `null`:

```
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

А во время попытки получить данные из базы получили сообщение, что *"у клиента нет разрешения на доступ к нужным данным"*, значит, что попытка авторизации завершилась неудачно. Значит пользователь не авторизован. Нужно править `config` и устанавливать верные значения.

Как только в этой строке будет не `null`:

```
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Тогда и будет пользователь авторизован и данные можно будет получить. Для справки:

- [firebase.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth)
- [firebase.auth.Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth)
- [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)